# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception length=0; index=0

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm using [libaums](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums) for reading file. I just copy from test file. But it give me an error if I'm not plug the USB.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

this is my code.

```
private void discoverDevice() {
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        UsbMassStorageDevice[] devices = UsbMassStorageDevice.getMassStorageDevices(this);
        device = devices[0];
        UsbDevice usbDevice = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        if (usbDevice != null && usbManager.hasPermission(usbDevice)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "received usb device via intent");
            setupDevice();
        } else {
            PendingIntent permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
            usbManager.requestPermission(device.getUsbDevice(), permissionIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is returning an empty array: ***UsbMassStorageDevice.getMassStorageDevices(this);***

Comment: It will throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as it is not able to find any usb. So `device = devices[0];` throws this exception.

Comment: thanks, it work fine... just add throws this exception.

Answer (score 1):

> Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception length=0; index=0

This line is causing the error. You should check for empty array before fetching the first element.

```
 device = devices[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

it work fine... just add throws this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
private void discoverDevice() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        UsbMassStorageDevice[] devices = UsbMassStorageDevice.getMassStorageDevices(this);
        devicea = devices[0];
        UsbDevice usbDevice = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        if (usbDevice != null && usbManager.hasPermission(usbDevice)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "received usb device via intent");
            setupDevice();
        } else {
            PendingIntent permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
            usbManager.requestPermission(devicea.getUsbDevice(), permissionIntent);
        }
    }
```

and call it by :

```
        try {
            discoverDevice();
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thank's for [codeRock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185670/coderock)